# double-double precision floating point as sum of two doubles

Tags: floating-point, arbitrary-precision, double-double-arithmetic

Following [papers and source code for double-double arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) for some time, I still can't find out how exactly a dd_real ( defined as `struct dd_real { double x[2];...}`) number is split into two doubles. Say if I initialize it with a string, `dd_real pi = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950";` what will be `pi.x[0]` and `pi.xi[1]`? I need to understand it and then write a hopefully small Python function that does it.

The reason I don't just want to call into the QD library is that I'd prefer to reimplement the correct split in Python so that I send my 35-digit precision constants (given as strings) as `double2` to CUDA code where it will be treated as double-double reals by the [GQD library](http://code.google.com/p/gpuprec/) -- the only library, it seems, to deal with extended precision calculations in CUDA. That unfortunately rules out mpmath too, on Python side.

Comment: It would be easier if you took an example in binary or in hexadecimal.  Even if someone literally answers your question (by telling you the values of `pi.x[0]` and `pi.x[1]`), you won't be able to make any sense of the split with respect to the original decimal value.

Comment: Also note that `double double` is in no way "arbitrary precision". It is only "more precision that IEEE 754 double precision, while taking advantage of the available double precision hardware".

Answer (score 6):

Say that you initialize your `double double` with the binary number:

```
1.011010101111111010101010101010000000101010110110000111011111101010010101010
  < ---                 52 binary digits         --- >< --- more digits --- >
```

Then one `double` will be `1.0110101011111110101010101010100000001010101101100001`
and the other will be `1.1011111101010010101010 * 2^-53`

When you add these two numbers (as reals), the sum is the initial value. The first one packs as many bits as possible in its 52-bit mantissa. The second one contains the remaining bits, with the appropriate exponent.