# How can I print a specific number of digits after decimal point in cpp?

Tags: c++

How can I print a specific number of digits after decimal point in cpp?

As like, if I want to print more than 30 digits after decimal point while dividing 22 by 7 then how can I? Plz!

Comment: Read a book about C++, more specifically primitive data types is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want an accurate result, you'll need to use arbitrary precision libraries, or roll your own long division algorithm to compute the value to 30 decimal places.  There is currently no built-in datatype in C++ that guarantees that many significant figures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is working code snippet of printing a certain amount of decimal points.
So couple things to note:
1)Library needed is iomanip.
2) fixed means everything after decimal point
3) setprecision() means number of digits.

If you don't put fixed then it would count whole numbers before the decimal point as well. However since you want 30 AFTER decimal point you put fixed and setprecision(30).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double answer = 22.0/7.0;
   cout << "22.0 / 7.0 = " << fixed << setprecision(30) << answer << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: using namespace std; ?

Comment: nice to fix the indentation as well

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks @SamRedway

Comment: `setprecision(30)` does not mean it will make the output *precise* to 30 decimal places.

Comment: @RawN Yes that is why I said you need fixed. Isn't it correct with fixed?

Comment: Double can only store 16 decimal digits.

Comment: Try using g++ compiler and you will see this output: 3.142857142857142793701541449991

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Which is plain wrong approximation after the 15th digit. The result should repeat `142857` over and over again.

Comment: @RawN, ah I see what you mean, I wonder why those specific garbage numbers after.

Comment: I guess it is pretty unlikely to even go over anything 16 precision points over anyways. As in most cases it won't make a significant difference in what you're doing. Probably not gonna use C++ if your doing something like that precise..

Comment: @paddy what do you mean? When would it be critical to use precisely more than 16 decimal points? I can only think of Embedded systems that need exact values, but not sure if they need that precise.

Comment: Okay [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943855/1553090).  It's common to require much higher precision when you have error in intermediate calculations which then scales to much larger error in a final result.  As for your comment on not using C++ for high-precision work, that's simply untrue.